# Arabic font on iPhone not working

Tags: fonts, arabic

The Arabic font called "Amiri" ([link](http://www.amirifont.org/)) doesn't work on an iPhone (when visiting the link, the proper Arabic characters don't show up).

Is there a way to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that iOS does not support *OpenType* fonts for complex scripts: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=92586, and Amiri is an *OpenType* font. The Arabic fonts shipped by Apple are *AAT* fonts and that is probably why they work fine.

See also this related discussion: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5281738